# Why are the java.util.logging levels: FINE, FINER, and FINEST not working?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

We are currently working on adding logging using `java.util.logging`. Like many other threads have suggested, we have adjusted both the `logger` and the `handler` levels to: `ALL` using a properties file. The output will show log messages at these log levels:

- `CONFIG`
- `INFO`
- `WARNING`
- `SEVERE`

But not log messages at the following log levels:

- `FINE`
- `FINER`
- `FINEST`

Here is our config file:

```
#Level for the logger. 
.level= ALL

#Controls the console handler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL

#Adjust this level to change which logging is output
ca.fcl.wam.util.Logging.level = ALL
```

The logging statements added are as follows:

```
log.log(Level.FINEST, "Finest");
log.log(Level.FINER, "FINER");
log.log(Level.FINE, "FINE");
log.log(Level.CONFIG, "CONFIG");
log.log(Level.INFO, "INFO");
log.log(Level.WARNING, "WARNING");
log.log(Level.SEVERE, "SEVERE");
log.finest("Finest Log");
log.finer("Finer Log");
log.fine("Fine Log");
log.config("Config Log");
log.info("Info Log");
log.warning("Warning Log");
log.severe("Severe Log");
```

Our log ends up as:

```
[2/24/16 14:16:41:691 CST] 0000005f Logging       C   CONFIG
[2/24/16 14:16:41:691 CST] 0000005f Logging       I   INFO
[2/24/16 14:16:41:691 CST] 0000005f Logging       W   WARNING
[2/24/16 14:16:41:691 CST] 0000005f Logging       E   SEVERE
[2/24/16 14:16:41:691 CST] 0000005f Logging       C   Config Log
[2/24/16 14:16:41:691 CST] 0000005f Logging       I   Info Log
[2/24/16 14:16:41:691 CST] 0000005f Logging       W   Warning Log
[2/24/16 14:16:41:691 CST] 0000005f Logging       E   Severe Log
```

Changing the levels in the config file behaves properly, unless it is set to: `ALL`, `FINE`, `FINER`, or `FINEST`. In each of those cases only.

Comment: I would assume your config is not being used.  You are missing the line which would attach a handler to a logger so if the config was being used you shouldn't see any output. Set everything to OFF and if you get output then you know your config is not being used.

Comment: What is the following setting in your properties file and why is it there: `ca.fcl.wam.util.Logging.level = ALL` ?

Comment: @jmehrens the config file is definitely being loaded. If I set it to off not logs will show, setting it to info will only show info, warning, and severe. Sean, this was added to set the level of an individual logger, just in case we ended up having multiples that we wanted to set separately.

Answer (score 1):

If that is really your entire config file, then you are missing the part where you set the handler:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Include code to output what the all the loggers have been set to after your log test has executed.

```
public class DebugLogging {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("ca.fcl.wam.util.Logging");

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        log.log(Level.FINEST, "Finest");
        log.log(Level.FINER, "FINER");
        log.log(Level.FINE, "FINE");
        log.log(Level.CONFIG, "CONFIG");
        log.log(Level.INFO, "INFO");
        log.log(Level.WARNING, "WARNING");
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "SEVERE");
        log.finest("Finest Log");
        log.finer("Finer Log");
        log.fine("Fine Log");
        log.config("Config Log");
        log.info("Info Log");
        log.warning("Warning Log");
        log.severe("Severe Log");
        printConfig();
    }

    private static void printConfig() {
        LogManager lm = LogManager.getLogManager();
        synchronized (lm) {
            Enumeration<String> e = lm.getLoggerNames();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                Logger l = lm.getLogger(e.nextElement());
                if (l != null) {
                    print(l, System.err);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void print(Logger l, PrintStream ps) {
        String scn = l.getClass().getSimpleName();
        ps.append("scn=").append(scn).append(", n=").append(l.getName())
                .append(", l=").append(String.valueOf(l.getLevel()))
                .append(", fl=").println(l.getFilter());
        for (Handler h : l.getHandlers()) {
            ps.append("\t").append(scn).append("->")
                    .append(h.getClass().getName()).append(", h=")
                    .append(String.valueOf(h.getLevel())).append(", fl=")
                    .append(String.valueOf(h.getFilter()));
        }
    }
}
```